# Position of bullet point when itemizing tcolorbox

Tags: itemize, tcolorbox

I'm interested in itemizing some `tcolorboxes`, but I want the bullet point to be at the top-left corner of the `tcolorbox`.  Below is an MWE,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{tcolorbox}[valign=top,colback=black]\textcolor{white}{How to get bullet to be at top of box?}\end{tcolorbox}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `box align=top` as additional option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe a bit too high ...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=black,box align=top]\textcolor{white}{How to get bullet to be at top of box?}\end{tcolorbox}
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To get a bit more fine control, one could combine this with `\raisebox`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \raisebox{0.2cm}{\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=black,box align=top]\textcolor{white}{How to get bullet to be at top of box?}\end{tcolorbox}}
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Version without `box align=top` (but you have to know, who large your box is):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \raisebox{-0.85cm}{\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=black]\textcolor{white}{How to get bullet to be at top of box?}\end{tcolorbox}}
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm using xelatex, and the document doesn't compile.  It throws an error `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/box align' and I am going 
to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

Comment: @user13317: No, your `tcolorbox` version is just too old! It was added in 2014 already. And if sam carter would have misspelled it, it would not produce the output ;-)

Comment: @user13317 I can confirm, that it works with `xetex`. What version are you using? I tested with Texlive2016.

Comment: @samcarter Here is the output from `tex --version TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
'

Comment: @user13317 I suggest installing a current version https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: @samcarter: (+1) , the O.P. can't upvote right now ;-)

Comment: @user13317 or see the version without `box align=top`. But this requires manual input of the box height.